# Phonegap plugin on iOS not calling native code

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I am trying to implement my first phonegap plugin (version 2.3) on iOS - but the call of the native function seems not to work.

My plugin is based on this introduction:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS

So I added to the plugins-section of config.xml:

```
<plugin name="Echo" value="Echo" />
```

my calling javascript:

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    $('#testBtn').submit(function () { 
        alert("test");
        var param = ["a", false];
        cordova.exec(
            function(winParam) { alert("ok");    },
            function(err)      { alert("error"); },
            "Echo", "echo", param);
        return false;
    });
}
```

(the alert in the first row gets called by pushing my testBtn, so the rest should also be executed...)

In my plugins-directory:

Echo.h:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface Echo : CDVPlugin

    - (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Echo.m:

```
#import "Echo.h"

@implementation Echo


- (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSLog(@"echo!");
}

@end
```

The echo-Function in Echo.m never gets called ... can anyone tell me why? I don't get any error messages - just nothing happens...

Comment: try to import the #import <Cordova/CDV.h> in your .m too

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: did you look into the xcode console window? the echo message should be there. The alert for ok or error is not going to appear because you don't call the [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry ... my fault. cordova-2.3.0.js was in the wrong folder. Thank you for your help, jcesar.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling in this step like you. then I Called that javascript function after device getting ready. Problem has solved. Now, Its working fine...